# Lexical or Preprocessor issue with Xcode 4.6.1

Tags: xcode, three20, lexical

My App could work with `Xcode 4.3.3` before. But when I want to make it for `adhoc` test by `Product -- Archive` with `Xcode 4.6.1`, following error appears:

> three20UI.h, Lexical or Preprocessor issue, 'Three20UI/TTTableImageItemCell.h' file not found.

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Three20UI/TTTableImageItemCell.h file is missing, go to your folder and then add this file again.

Comment: thanks Ahmed Z. for your prompt reply. But Three20UI/TTTableImageItemCell.h file is not missing, it is right there in my project and folder. I tried to delete it ( by deleting refrence ) in my project and add it again, but still get the same error.

Comment: I meet the same error here. Xcode 5 can not find a file just in my C++ project.